# Connecting Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded SQL Server Management studio 2012 ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe. But there are no items in the SQL Server Services.Here is the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO1mE.png) Am I suppose to download anything else other than this. Please let me know the correct way to start a SQL Server Instance to connect to a database Engine.

Comment: Management Studio is ***ONLY*** the management GUI - but ***NOT*** the actual database **engine**! You need to download the Express **with Tools** edition to get both the engine and the management GUI !

Comment: Can you provide me with the link to download the same?

Comment: Type SSMS or SQL in the start menu...

Comment: [Scott Hanselman has us all covered](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx). Get the "with Tools" or "with Advanced Services" versions - both include the database *and* the management GUI

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this version of Sql Server of no use?

Comment: This is **just** the management GUI - it is **NOT** SQL Server (the engine!). SSMS is a great tool - but you ***need to have*** a SQL Server ***database engine*** to connect to first!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Sql Server to get services.  Management Studio is just a tool that works with Sql Server.

Express:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions-express

Free Developer Edition:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this version of SSMS of no use?

Comment: No its definitely useful.  SSMS used to be included in the Sql Server install.  I believe that now it must be installed separate.  SSMS is very useful for managing your database instances.  Some regard SSMS to be geared towards DBA and Database Developers and Visual Studio (SSDT) includes database projects geared towards traditional .Net developers.

Comment: I have downloaded ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe. People are suggesting to download SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe which includes both the client tools and the database engine. Is there a way to add database engine tool to ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe? I do not want to download it all over again.

Comment: That download includes advanced services (reporting services)  If you only need the database engine and have already installed SSMS you can just download the link I provided.  Here is a good link describing different downloads : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b91f001f-b5a0-438a-ac42-e77005609318/confused-by-download-links?forum=sqlexpress